# Calls to SchTasks remotely to delete tasks fails with multi connection error from C#

Tags: scheduled-tasks

From c# code I call schtasks to delete some scheduled tasks. I make the first call and I get this error returned:

*ERROR: Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed....*

Here's the code that runs the process:

```
        Process stProc = new Process();

        stProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        stProc.StartInfo.FileName = "SCHTASKS.exe";
        stProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        stProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        stProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        stProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        stProc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;

        stProc.Start();
        stProc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        stProc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        stProc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_OutputDataReceived);
        stProc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_ErrorDataReceived);
        stProc.WaitForExit();
        stProc.Close();
        stProc.Dispose();
```

My arguments are correct as per: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx

Just to make sure that my connection is not hanging around, I create a new process to kill it before every delete call:

```
StartProcess(args);
        Process x = new Process();
        x.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
        x.StartInfo.Arguments = @" net use \\servername\ipc$ /delete";
        x.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        x.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        x.Start();
```

Not sure what's up here. Might it be someone else that's using this machine and so my calls can't get through?

Any ideas appreciated!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938120

I used the IP address of the machine.